# How does Ubuntu Desktop differ from Laptop

Tags: boot, grub2, laptop, .desktop

I have Ubuntus on my laptop and desktop, and for curiosity reason I tried to mount my desktop ssd  on my laptop SATA to see if it is bootable, and it turned out that it can't, the motherboard simply says no bootable environment was found.

And for laptop to desktop vice versa, the only difference is that when I mounted the laptop ssd on desktop and booted, the grub shows that it tried to repair some error, however I ceased the operation because I am affair the grub may change my boot environment to desktop one.

So I am just curious that how ubuntu differs between desktop and laptop, apart from battery control/mouse pad controls etc..

Thanks!

Comment: its more about hardware compatability

Comment: It is mandatory that Laptop will have WiFi and Bluetooth incorporated out of box. Where as in desktops, they are not unless you assemble your own. After purchasing desktop, you may go for USB pluggable WiFI or Bluetooth which will eat away your usb ports, so you will be left with want of ports. Major advantage of desktops are that they easily upgradable not only to O/S releases but also hardware components. Desktops are little expensive to maintain because they need UPS support. These are the apparent differences what I feel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the manufacturer guidline of compatibility, I realized the problem was that my SSD on desktop is 1TB and for most of the laptops nowadays don't support up to 512 GB SSD ( you can add 512*2 for two SATAs).

Comment: +1! do accept your answer when you can. and it might be fixable with a bios upgrade if "they" ever provide one